# How to not deselect a radio button when I click it again?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, radio-button

I have successfully implemented the radio button from a volley. The example data in my volley is `1, 2, 3`. When I select radio button 1 and then I select radio button 2, radio 1 is unchecked. This situation is normal, but when I select radio button 2 again the radio button becomes deselected and I can't select it anymore.

This is the code I put in the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.APP_PUPUKKUJANG_MART, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String whois = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConfig.USER_WHOIS,null);
    row_index = -1;
    holder.itemView.setTag(service.get(position));
    final ServiceCourier p = service.get(position);
    holder.service.setText(p.getService());
    holder.desc.setText(p.getDescription());
    holder.cost.setText("Rp "+String.format(Locale.US, "%1$,.0f", Double.valueOf(p.getCost())).replace(",","."));
    holder.etd.setText(p.getEtd());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    View.OnClickListener rbClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) v;
            if(lastCheckedRB != null){
                ActivityCheckout.updateTextViewIscek("0");
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.APP_, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("ongkir_service", p.getService());
            editor.putString("ongkir_description", p.getDescription());
            editor.putString("ongkir_cost", p.getCost());
            editor.putString("ongkir_etd", p.getEtd());
            editor.apply();
            String cost = String.format(Locale.US, "%1$,.0f", Double.valueOf(p.getCost()));
            Double total_order = ActivityCheckout.getTextViewTotal();
            Double tf = Double.valueOf(p.getCost())+total_order;
            ActivityCheckout.updateTextViewIscek("1");
            ActivityCheckout.updateTextView("Rp "+cost.replace(",","."));
            ActivityCheckout.updateTotal_fees("Rp "+String.format(Locale.US, "%1$,.0f", tf).replace(",","."));
        }
    };
    holder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(rbClick);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "but when i select radio button 2 again the radio button select cold not not selected and always unselected"? It's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: @LarsH sorry,, i mean the radio button data is 3 , 1. radiobutton1, 2. radiobutton2, 3. radiobutton3 .. when i select radio button number 1 and then i select radiobutton number 2 the radio button 1 is unselected and of course radio button 2 is selected but when i select again radio button 2 the radiobutton 2 not selected and automatic to unselect

Comment: Do you mean that if you tap radiobutton2 a second time, your onClick() listener method doesn't get called a second time? Or do you mean that if you tap radiobutton2 a second time, radiobutton2's visual appearance on the screen changes to indicate that it's not selected anymore? (Also I don't know what you mean by "volley.")

Comment: @LarsH yes when i clic 2x radio button the radio button is always unselected but i want is selected, btw volley is library that making http call for get api response